# Logic to prevent insertion if there are no available slots

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET with C# and I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement a logic statement that will stop the system from allowing another reservation to be taken if the trailer for canoes and kayaks is full.  The issue is the trailer will hold canoes and kayaks, but there's a lot of different combinations.

There are 5 "rows" on the trailer that count upwards vertically, and 2 "columns" that dissect the 5 rows in the middle.  I will draw you a diagram to show you what it looks like, and what boats can go where.  "C" will stand for Canoe and "K" will stand for Kayak. The trailer looks like this:

```
C only|C only  }
______|______  }  BOAT TRAILER
 1C\2K|1C\2K   }
______|______  }     
 1C\2K|1C\2K   } 
______|______  }
 1C\2K|1C\2K   }
______|______  }
C only| C only }
______|______  }
```

So my question is, what's the best option as far as coding and logic is concerned to not take any more "reservations" when the trailer is full? This application will be a .aspx form that will do an insert command to SQL server taking customer information.

Comment: Any effort so far? Please show your code.

Comment: You should put this on the stack mathematics board too, someone would probably enjoy solving this.

Comment: I'm currently in the design stage, and doing E-R diagrams etc, but this is the only thing currently holding me back.  The only idea I have so far is to make a giant IF + Else statement with all of the possible combinations.

Comment: So you mean you can take a total of 10 canoes or 20 kayaks? Just weight a kayak as 1 and canoe as 2. If total reservations < 20, still room. But of course you have to check when there are 19 (only room for another kayak, not canoe)

Comment: @AdmiralAdama Only levels 2-4 can take kayaks (2 each) so 12 kayaks is the max per trailer, while 10 canoes if every slot had a canoe.

Comment: Oh I think you have to take at least 4 canoes? Ok so then you are only checking up to 12, after 4 canoes have reserved a spot.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama if it makes any difference, we don't HAVE to take any canoes. We could just end up with 12 kayaks on a trailer, or 6 canoes and 8 kayaks.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum BoatType : int
{
    Kayak = 1,
    Canoe = 2
}

public class BoatReservation
{
    public int ReservationID { get; set; }
    public BoatType ReservationBoatType { get; set; }
}

public class BoatTrailer
{
    public List<BoatReservation> CanoeSlots = new List<BoatReservation>();
    public List<BoatReservation> RegularSlots = new List<BoatReservation>();

    public BoatTrailer()
    {
    }

    public bool AddBoat(BoatReservation b)
    {
        bool boatAdded = false;
        switch (b.ReservationBoatType)
        {
            case BoatType.Canoe:
                if (CanoeSlots.Count() < 4)
                {
                    CanoeSlots.Add(b);
                    boatAdded = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    var reg = RegularSlots.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt16(x.ReservationBoatType));
                    if (reg <= 10)
                    {
                        RegularSlots.Add(b);
                        boatAdded = true;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case BoatType.Kayak:
                {
                    var reg = RegularSlots.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt16(x.ReservationBoatType));
                    if (reg <= 11)
                    {
                        RegularSlots.Add(b);
                        boatAdded = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        return boatAdded;
    }

    public void RemoveBoat(BoatReservation b)
    {
        switch (b.ReservationBoatType)
        {
            case BoatType.Kayak:
                if (RegularSlots.Contains(b))
                {
                    RegularSlots.Remove(b);
                }
                break;

            case BoatType.Canoe:
                if (RegularSlots.Contains(b))
                {
                    RegularSlots.Remove(b);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CanoeSlots.Contains(b))
                    {
                        CanoeSlots.Remove(b);
                        if (RegularSlots.Where(fb => fb.ReservationBoatType == BoatType.Canoe).Count() > 0)
                        {
                            //Move Reservation From Regular to Canoe Only With Opening
                            BoatReservation mv = RegularSlots.FindLast(fb => fb.ReservationBoatType == BoatType.Canoe);
                            RegularSlots.Remove(mv);
                            CanoeSlots.Add(mv);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public string AvailableSlots()
    {
        string Output = string.Empty;

        int AvailableCanoeCnt = (4 - CanoeSlots.Count()) + ((12 - RegularSlots.Count()) / 2);
        int AvailableKayakCnt = (12 - RegularSlots.Count());

        Output = string.Format("Canoe Slots Left: {0}   Kayak Slots Left {1} ", AvailableCanoeCnt, AvailableKayakCnt);

        return Output;
    }
}
```

Quick class that handles reservations (both adding and deleting) of canoes/kayaks to fit a trailer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best question for this site but I will provide a pseudo structure for this.

```
Trailer Object
   JustCanoes int
   CanoeKayakBlend int
```

When reserving...

```
If the reservation is for a canoe, and the JustCanoes value is < 4, then increase JustCanoes by 1
   If JustCanoes is >= 4
      If CanoeKayakBlend <= 10
          increase CanoeKayakBlend by 2
      else
          Sorry no reservation available


If the reservation is for a kayak
    If CanoeKayakBlend <= 11
          increase CanoeKayakBlend by 1
    else
          Sorry no reservation available
```

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and simplistic implementation: Here's the `Compartment` class

```
class Compartment
    {
        private readonly int _maxCanoe;
        private readonly int _maxKayak;
        private int _currentCanoe;
        private int _currentKayak;
        private readonly int _id;
        private bool _fullCanoe;
        private bool _fullKayak;

        public Compartment(int id, int maxC, int maxK)
        {
            _id = id;
            _maxCanoe = maxC;
            _maxKayak = maxK;

            _currentCanoe = _currentKayak = 0;

            UpdateCapacityStatus();
        }

        private void UpdateCapacityStatus()
        {
            _fullCanoe = _maxCanoe == _currentCanoe;
            _fullKayak = _maxKayak == _currentKayak;
        }

        private string Status
        {
            get { return IsFull() ? "FULL" : "Space available"; }
        }

        public bool IsFull()
        {
            return _fullKayak && _fullCanoe;
        }

        public void AddCanoe()
        {
            _fullKayak = true; // disable adding kayak

            _currentCanoe = _currentCanoe + 1;

            _fullCanoe = _maxCanoe == _currentCanoe; //update canoe status
        }

        public void AddKayak()
        {
            _fullCanoe = true; //disable adding canoe

            _currentKayak = _currentKayak + 1;

            _fullKayak = _maxKayak == _currentKayak; //update kayak status
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Id: {5}, Status: {0}, with {1} of {2} canoes or {3} of {4} kayaks", Status, _currentCanoe, _maxCanoe, _currentKayak, _maxKayak, _id);
        }

        public bool CanAddCanoe()
        {
            return !_fullCanoe;
        }

        public bool CanAddKayak()
        {
            return !_fullKayak;
        }
    }
```

And here's the driver console app to test, to use it you should refactor it of course.

`class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var trailer = new List
            {
                new Compartment(1, 1, 0),
                new Compartment(2, 1, 0),
                new Compartment(3, 1, 2),
                new Compartment(4, 1, 2),
                new Compartment(5, 1, 2),
                new Compartment(6, 1, 2),
                new Compartment(7, 1, 2),
                new Compartment(8, 1, 2),
            };

```
        foreach (var compartment in trailer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(compartment.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press c for canoe or k for kayak");


        var keepGoing = true;

        while (keepGoing)
        {
            var input = Console.Read();

            if (input == 99 || input == 107) //99 c, 107 k
            {
                if (trailer.All(c => c.IsFull()))
                {
                    keepGoing = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (input == 99)
                    {
                        if(!trailer.Any(t=>t.CanAddCanoe()))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Cannot add a canoe!!!!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var firstAvailable = trailer.First(c => c.CanAddCanoe());
                            firstAvailable.AddCanoe();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (input == 107)
                    {
                        if (!trailer.Any(t => t.CanAddKayak()))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Cannot add a kayak!!!!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var firstAvailable = trailer.First(c => c.CanAddKayak());
                            firstAvailable.AddKayak();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Press c for canoe or k for kayak");
                    }
                }

                foreach (var compartment in trailer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(compartment.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}`
```